# Need Help with Inserting in database

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite

i m a newbie... I need help with inser statement .. my code is as follows.. the code runs but it does not add anything inside the database. plz can anyone suggest me why is it so..

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)Sender{

    CGPoint loc;
    loc.x = [_x.text floatValue];
    loc.y = [_y.text floatValue];
    if(loc.x != 0 || loc.y != 0 ) 
    {
    [_x endEditing:YES];
    [_y endEditing:YES];
    [_name endEditing:YES];
        NSString *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];   
        NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:loc.x];
        NSNumber *y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:loc.y];               

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cities.sqlite"];

        sqlite3 *database;

        if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *sqlStatement = "insert into table (name, xLoc,yLoc,date) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {
                sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [_name.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_double( compiledStatement, 2, [x doubleValue]);

                sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement, 3, [y doubleValue]);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [date UTF8String] ,-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            }

        char* errmsg;
        sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

            if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
                NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
            } else {
                NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %lld", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);




        [[self navigationController]popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Wrong Co-ordinates described." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Go Back" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
}
```

THanks guyz i got it... edited the above code now it runs and submit data in database..

Comment: If it runs... without errors... but nothing is in the database... have you done a commit?

Comment: yes... it just that it does not update data base.. is the code right.. ?
btw check the date syntax.. if i wanna add date also to my table will the above code do.. Thanks..

Comment: sorry but i did not get it last time... can u plz edit mine code.. how to commit in end.. i m a new and its mine first time with db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind the values to the prepared statement, but it does not look like you ever call commit.

Comment: oh sry did not get it.. plz edit mine code.. where habe i got to call commit... does not step does the same business... sry m a newbie..